# CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE error. How to Add Runtime Libs to NDK Compiled Code

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, apk

I have a c++ application, specifically a device driver(no gui), that I wrote for linux and built with a makefile. I want this driver to run on an android device(arm64 running android 29), so I compiled the driver successfully on my linux machine by using the android NDK standalone toolchain in my makefile and liked with the appropriate arm64 dependencies.

When I push the code to the android via adb shell and try to run, I get the error:

```
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "./gdriver": library "libudev.so.1" not found
```

The driver has a whole bunch of similar dependencies, so I have some questions:
Where do I place the libraries/headers so the android can find them at runtime?
Is there a way to package my compiled NDK executable with the libraries as an apk or similar in Android Studio?
Is there a way to package it so it runs out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to package my compiled NDK executable with the libraries as an apk or similar in Android Studio?

I see the following simplest way:

1. Create new project in AS: `Select a Project Template -> Native C++`
2. Rework your cmake for executable `gdriver` to compile library `libgdriver.so` instead
3. Call your entry function from `libgdriver.so` in `Java_com_example_myapplication_MainActivity_stringFromJNI` (function from AS template code of `libnative-lib.so` )
4. Add linking your libraries in `native-lib` cmake:

```
target_link_libraries(native-lib gdriver udev)
```

This is just an example, you can implement it however you want, for example without `native-lib` at all, but main point is to recompile your executable like library and call its entry function from Activity (in our case via JNI). All your libraries would be a part of APK.

Answer (score 0):

Many versions of Android won't use native libraries that don't follow the pattern `lib*.so`. It's possible that the problem is the name of your library.